# Convolution & Bessel function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution, bessel-functions

I'm about to compute a convolution, which is given as [Eq. (12)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/netzT.png)

Recall the Jacobi expansion of Bessel function, which is given by
$\exp(iz\cos\theta)=\sum_mi^mJ_m(z)\exp(im\theta)$, while performing the convolution of two Fourier transforms here we have
$$\mathcal{F}\left\{\exp[i(\rho\cos(\Omega t+\phi)+\gamma\cos(2\Omega t+2\phi)]\right\}.$$
I'm just wondering if there's anything related to the Jacobi expansion or some other tricks in performing the convolution here. A Huge thank!

Comment: Is $x=z$ in the Jacobi expansion?

Comment: Uh yeah. Sorry for the typo here.